# some elements in iframe is not loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm using an iframe to load an external website to my webpage. iframe successfully loads the website. Then I compare the dom with the actual website dom. But I can see that some elements(very few) are not loading in iframe. What would be the reason for that?

I found the reason that elements created inside `window === window.parent` check is not loading inside the iframe. Is there a way to load the content inside this check? I'm also using chrome-extension to load the iframe. so is there anything can be done using `chrome.webRequest`?

Comment: Any code reference or snapshots to check what is going on? Only few elements are displayed on your website as might be from the actual website only that is what is been allowed to render on another website via iFrames.

Comment: you mean it is possible for other websites to set which all elements to render in iframe?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Websites like Facebook, Twitter, etc. render only that part what the wanted to be rendered via IFrames. But it will be more clear if you attach some code or snapshots of the UI, actually what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

is it responsive? maybe it's your iframe size issue

Comment: no, it is not the responsive issue, because I'm loading the iframe in the entire screen